# Trying to index a Parent results in a nil value

Tags: lua, roblox

Error:

> 16:16:03.496 - Workspace.Storeroom.Pile of Crates.Wood Crate.Script:17: attempt to index field 'Parent' (a nil value)

Script:

```
local db = true

local clickdetector = script.Parent:WaitForChild('ClickDetector')

clickdetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)

local randomizer = math.random(1,6)

if randomizer == 1 or 2 or 3 then

script.Parent:Destroy()

local gift = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("Blue Keycard")

if db == true then

db = false

gift:Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack

wait(1)

db = true           

end

end

if randomizer == 4 or 5 then

script.Parent:Destroy()

local gift = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("Red Keycard")

if db == true then

db = false

gift:Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack

wait(1)

db = true

end

end

if randomizer == 6 then

script.Parent:Destroy()

local gift = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("Green Keycard")

if db == true then

db = false

gift:Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack

wait(1)

db = true           

end

end

end)
```

Answer (score 0):

> if randomizer == 1 or 2 or 3 then 
>   if randomizer == 4 or 3 then

These lines won't work as you think it should. It doesn't check if `randomizer` value is in some set of predefined values. Expression `randomizer == 1 or 2 or 3` evaluates (depending on `randomizer` exact value) either to `true` or to `2`, which is interpreted as `true` in `if/then` construct.

If you really want to check the value against the list, you should do something like:

```
local set1 = {1=true, 2=true, 3=true}
local set2 = {4=true, 5=true}

--  somewhere much later
if set1[randomizer] then .. end
```

Start with fixing this issue.